# How to select string until a certain character in java

Tags: java, regex

I have string where only a certain part should be selected. until i reach a character.
Ex. `5000 - 10000` i want only `5000` until the `-` or `the white space`.

```
input.replace("","");
```

What Regular expression should i be using.

Comment: Why are you using `replace`? It sounds like you might want to use a regular expressions, find the index of the first occurrence, then use substring...

Comment: "the "-" or the white space." Which? Or either?

Comment: either 50000-100000 or 5000 - 10000

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
final String beforeDash = input.split("-")[0].trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem:

```
String[] parts = input.split("-");
```

The string you are looking for is then in parts[0].

If you want to split on the whitespace instead of the dash, use string.split(" ").

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below code which matches the first space or `-` upto the last character. Replacing those matched characters with an empty string will gave you the desired output.

```
input.replaceAll("[\\s-].*","");
```

You could also use `string.split` function.

```
String[] parts = input.split("[\\s-]");
System.out.println(parts[0]);
```

The above split function would split the input according to a space or a hyphen. Printing the index 0 from the splitted parts will give you the desired output.